# Libgdx batch draw invisible texture

Tags: java, libgdx

I have the following code:

```
batch.draw(this.getTexture(), getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(),
                getWidth(), getHeight(), 1, 1, this.getRotation(),
                getRegionX(), getRegionY(), getRegionWidth(), getRegionHeight(),
                false, false);
```

which should the texture, it is definitely not null, however it's invisible.

Because it is drawing the player i don't think it is outside of the view.

Comment: Did you set x,y,width,height ?

Comment: Yes i did set them in the constructor

Comment: What are rotation, regionx, regiony etc

Comment: If you are using a simple structure what does 
        batch.draw(getTexture(), getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(), getWidth(), getHeight()); produce

Comment: with little tweaks it shows, however i need to apply rotation somehow to the batch

Comment: I don't know your regionWidth and regionHeight but maybe they are 0. Try the one above what is the result ?

batch.draw(this.getTexture(), getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(),
                getWidth(), getHeight(), 1, 1, this.getRotation(),
                getRegionX(), getRegionY(), getWidth(), getHeight(),
                false, false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `regionWidth` and `regionHeight` may be `0`. Try the code below

```
batch.draw(this.getTexture(), getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(), 
    getWidth(), getHeight(), 1, 1, this.getRotation(), 
    getRegionX(),getRegionY(), getWidth(), getHeight(), false, false);
```